# Google APi- Redirect URL

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to add url http://192.168.137.129:8080/0/rest/cloudAdded as Redirect URL in Google Console APi for my project but it is not allowing to save it. But I want to use this as redirect URL

I have a Server made in Android Application and I am accessing that server in my browser in laptop. I want to open Google Authentication for Goole Drive APi in browser. So I want to use this URL as redirect URL

Answer (score 1):

I tried your URI in a test project on Google APIs and saw this error:

> Invalid Redirect: http://192.168.137.129:8080/0/rest/cloudAdded must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)

Put another way, Google error message is saying that you can't use an IP address in the Authorized Redirect URI. You'll need to use a publicly hosted domain name for your app.

There is a very useful trick if you are using this server for testing or development. I recommend using [xip.io](http://xip.io/) to solve your problem. It's a custom DNS service that lets you map an arbitrary domain name to a desired IP address. In this case it will solve your problem of

So for development, try using `http://192.168.137.129.xip.io:8080/0/rest/cloudAdded` as your Authorized Redirect URI. Google accepts it because it uses a public domain name. Your app should like it because the DNS maps to its IP address.

Comment: For development I can use it but what will happen in case of Production

Comment: I am using this IP for DropBox and Box redirect. I want to use the same for Google Drive. Else will have to change the server to catch it

Comment: @dkumar What IP address will your server use in production? You would typically register a public domain name to map to your production IP address.

Comment: No its the IP given above

Comment: For production use, you may consider registering a public domain and point it at that IP address. You'll be able to use that domain in your Authorized Redirect URI and it will be stable and robust for production use. Keep in mind that that IP address is only accessible on a private network. This might work for an app that is deployed privately but won't work for one that is generally available.

Answer (score 0):

one can work around the requirement for a `FQDN` ...

a) by setting the redirect URL to a publicly available resource (public IP), with a `FQDN` domain name; this example uses a redirect URL alike `https://api.acme.com/drive/redirect`. to have any `FQDN` is the precondition; because nothing else can be entered (one can also add two redirect URL there, if one needs redirect URLs for a development and a production environment).

b) then add this rewrite rule into an `.htaccess` file in the web-root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # dispatch oAuth2 postbacks to localhost
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/drive/redirect(/|)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)&scope=(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:8080 [QSA,L]

 </IfModule>
```

c) this will deliver the auth-code, which then can be exchanged against a new access token. the advance is, that the auth-code is not being stored somewhere on a remote host, but is forwarded.